# Rails Route based on something different than ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So currently I have something like /users/1/ when I want to view a user profile. How can I go through routes.rb to change that to /user/chiggins/ where chiggins is a unique username?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need is to override to_param method in User model:

```
class User
  def to_param
   username
  end
end
```

Then rails will use it automagically for routing. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param

Comment: Alright, I added that little bit in, but I'm getting the following error: http://chigstuff.com/uploads/user_error.jpg

Comment: Nevermind, I found my problem. My show method was doing "@user = User.find(:params[:id])", I changed it around to search by the username.

Comment: Change code in your controller: not User.find(params[:id]) but User.find_first_by_username(params[:id]) or change body of to_param to "#{self.id}-#{self.username}"

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility to consider would be the friendly_id gem - https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there is a `:param` argument on the resource declaration.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can get per-resource identifier customization by redefining the member_scope and nested_scope methods on the Resource instance.

```rb
resources :users do
  @scope[:scope_level_resource].tap do |u|
    def u.member_scope
      "#{path}/:username"
    end

    def u.nested_scope
      "#{path}/:#{singular}_username"
      # member_scope also usable here, assuming username will be nowhere in nested routes.
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding the question about #nested_scope below: It gets used when you do something like this in routing:

```rb
resources :members do
  resources :playlists, only: :index
end
```

Then, the param would be :member_username instead of just :username.  This is useful in the playlists controller when assembling the collection so you can infer the scope of the request.

Comment: I understand "#{path}/:username", to overide automatic generated routes, but I don't understand what mean "nested_scope" method?!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define a route with a custom param:

```
match "/users/:username" => "users#show"
```

In your controller, the plain old params[:id] will be params[:username], and you can get the user from de DB using:

```
User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

Comment: I just added that first line to my routes.db, though instead of using :username I'm still required to use :id